# Where to look for updates on new features/enhancement additions to Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, support

The development team at Stack Exchange makes changes/enhancements in the Stack Overflow UI, editor, badges and scoring systems.

Is there a way for the users to track what update will be rolled out and when? It will let the users know what changes to expect in the system beforehand. This way there will be no surprises.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most large changes will be announced prior to implementation on [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com) or [here, Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com). For example, a large change to user profiles is [currently underway](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249951/help-us-test-the-shiny-new-user-activity-page-plus-a-bunch-of-new-features). The team is requesting feedback on the new design, and that post is being shown in the sidebar of all main sites.

Also, an archive of historical changes is available at [on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange), and you can look for implemented user-requested features in the [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) tag here (or [on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-completed), but those may not pertain specifically to Stack Overflow).

Comment: While this is helpful, the MSO link is a gathering of noticeable changes noted by users, not any true changelog. It would be cool to see a true changelog for design updates although, I don't really see it as a priority.